# Transform between Kinect skeleton base frame and camera frame

Tags: openni, openi-tracker, openni-camera

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am trying to use the ROS NI drivers (openni_camera) with the Kinect, and additionally use openni_tracker to get the transforms for the joints for a detected skeleton. However, the joint transforms are published under the "/openni_depth" frame, which doesn't exist in the tree of frames published by the kinect_frames.launch file. Setting an identity static transform between /openni_depth_frame and /openni_depth didn't seem to give correct results.

Does anybody know the transform between /openni_depth and a frame in the hierarchy published by the driver?

Thanks,

Peter Brook

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/9264/transform-between-kinect-skeleton-base-frame-and-camera-frame/) by [pbrook](https://answers.ros.org/users/226/pbrook/) on ROS Answers with karma: 226 on 2011-03-02

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [pbrook](https://answers.ros.org/users/226/pbrook/) on 2011-03-07**:
That kforge link didn't seem to work, I get a 404 error. It seems that https://kforge.ros.org/openni/ isn't on the server?

**Comment by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) on 2011-03-07**:
I've opened a ticket to make these line work by default again. https://kforge.ros.org/openni/Trac/ticket/6

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I just tested it now, openni_depth was changed to default to openni_depth_frame so that also needs to be the default in openni_tracker.

I'm updating the code to be parameterizable with parameter ~/camera_frame_id defaulting to openni_depth_frame.

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2011-03-07

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [KoenBuys](https://answers.ros.org/users/134/koenbuys/) on 2011-03-07**:
It might be interesting to have the output printed in ROS_INFO or ROS_DEBUG format.